# Iphone HTTP post to a php page

Tags: php, iphone, post, asihttprequest

I'm currently trying to post data to a php age.
Here's my iphone code:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
request.timeOutSeconds = 5;
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:tmpComment forKey:@"content"];
[request setPostValue:tmpPoint forKey:@"point"];

NSLog(@"comment : %@",tmpComment);// it appears right
NSLog(@"point:%@",tmpPoint);//
request.delegate=self;
[request startAsynchronous];
```

And my php page is like:

```
print_r($_POST);
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
print_r($_GET);
```

and the response string is like:

```
Array
(
)
GET
Array
(
)
```

No Post data here.
So I'm quite confused about why the request method is still "GET" but not "POST".
Should I configure the php server somewhere？

Thanks a lot!~

ANSWER:: 
I found that the url should be "http://myurl/index.php" rather than "http://myurl/" to avoid redirects.

Thanks for Ayesh K's help and hint~!

Comment: Besides, I can post data to this php server from another php page~

Comment: looks like the problem is in the client. Although you make a POST request, server receives it as a GET. Does your server has any rewrite/redirects ?

Comment: I don't know whether it contains, but this page does not have any code about rewrite/redirects..

Comment: Don't forget to answer your own question with the solution when SO allows you to!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the url should be `http://myurl/index.php` rather than `http://myurl/` to avoid redirects.